# Wordpress .htaccess doesn't remove www from website's URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Looking at the code, this should be working (its working for other websites/subdomains i'm working on)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Edit: the website is on a Redirect Loop now.

Comment: The rules corresponding to the www redirect are commented out.

Comment: Isn't your www rewrite commented out? Remove the `#`

Comment: wait, i remember now, commented that because its throwing a "Redirect loop"

Comment: Do you have the www. in the wp-config.php file settings also?

Comment: @Aravona i dont see where in the wp-config.php file i should change it, could you point it out please?

Comment: @Gazta It'll only be there if you have `define('WP_SITEURL'` and `define('WP_HOME',` set.

Comment: okay, that fixed it! tyvm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it going into Wordpress settings > General > Website URL and adding "www." to the domain :)

Answer (score -1):

your redirect should be first before WordPress handles the request.

like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```